# Where does Discord store its cache on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I have been using windows for the last 2 years and recently switched to Ubuntu (20.04). Surely loving it but a lot of things to learn so wanted to ask that where does my discord store its cache because it has been creating a lot of cache since installed and wanted to remove some of the accumulated cache as it has started filling up the storage on my device.

Any help will be appreciated!
**Thank you.**

Comment: Try Disk Usage Analyzer, included with Ubuntu Desktop, for a real-data snapshot of what's using up your disk space, and where those files are located. Use your Desktop Search (the super key or the little grid icon at the bottom of your shortcut bar) to find it.

Comment: Tried both nothing about discord cache showing up @user535733

Comment: Try again: If Disk Usage Analyzer says that your Discord cache is too small to be noticeable, then your assumption that the Discord cache has "*started filling up the storage*" seems untrue or invalid. The tool will also tell you exactly what IS really filling up your storage.

Comment: Ok got it. It wasnt discord it was a node module. Thanks, but if you ever get the location of discord please please inform me too. Thanks again

Comment: What is the output of `du -sh ~/.config/discord` ?

Comment: haha ofc it was node module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord saves its cache in your home folder, in the `~/.config/discord` subfolder.

On my system it is about 500 Mb, and this not too big amount of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a node module but learnt something anyway!